# Is Xenonauts deterministic?

Tags: xenonauts

Is Xenonauts deterministic with a predetermined seed for a savegame or is the dice rolled each time completely new when a random event occurs.

That means:
**If you load an earlier save and repeat all actions exactly the same as before, will the result be exactly the same?**

Comment: Or, simply(?) -- Can you savescum in Xenonauts.

Comment: Well, savescumming is still possible in a deterministic game (just try something else each time you load), so that alone would not really answer my question.

Comment: I think it re-randomises the RNG seed each time. I've loaded saves and had different results but I don't know if the actions were identical.

Answer (score -1):

My experience is like this:

- Tactical part is deterministic.
- Globe part is random.

I normally do not replay a mission exactly the same after I load it, but the aliens are exactly at the same locations and sometimes, if my actions are close enough, it seems like they are behaving the same.  There still might be some randomness involved in the way the act.  There is definitely randomness in the shots and damage, and that eventually affects theirs actions as well.

As for the globe part - it is clearly random every time.  You will get the next attack proximately at the same date, but the number of UFOs, their location and actions are different every time I reload a game.

Comment: If accuracy and damage aren't deterministic, then it's not deterministic.

Comment: If actions are similar enough, mission replay could be close to the original.  If actions are different, replay may be not as similar.  So while randomness for the shots is different it does not necessarily mean the replay would be completely different.

It probably depends on your intent.  If you are thinking about reloading the game after every unfavorable weapon shot - you may say it is not deterministic.  But my experience is that it could also be quite the same even after a reload.  Sometimes I even do something differently on purpose, so it would not be so boringly identical :)